# Test Class help can't figure out how to cover last line

Tags: apex, unit-test

I Wrote/Borrowed(copied) some Apex on how to use the BusinessHours class.  I then wrote my test class by am only getting 3/4 (75%) coverage.  I'm not sure how to test the last line that isn't being tested.  I've tried system.assertNotEqual but that didn't change the coverage.

```
    trigger calcBusinessHours on Escalation__c (before insert, before update) {

    BusinessHours stdBusinessHours = [select id from businesshours where isDefault = true];

        for (Escalation__c so : Trigger.new) {
            if ((so.CreatedDate != NULL) && (stdBusinessHours != NULL) && (so.SLA__c == 'Standard')) {
            so.SLA_Due_Date__c = BusinessHours.addGmt (stdBusinessHours.id, so.CreatedDate, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L);
            }
      }
 }



    @isTest

 public class calcBusinessHoursTest {
    static testMethod void calcBusinessHours(){
        BusinessHours stdBusinessHours = [select id from businesshours where isDefault = true];

        Escalation__c e = new Escalation__c();
        e.Case__c = '500300000015GUM';
        e.Account__c = '00130000000cfAy';
        e.SLA__c = 'Standard';
        e.SLA_Due_Date__C = NULL;      
        insert e;

        }
    }
```

It says that `so.SLA_Due_Date__c = BusinessHours.addGmt (stdBusinessHours.id, so.CreatedDate, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L);` is the line that is not getting tested.  Any hints into the right direction would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if CreatedDate is null, and if so, use the current time:

```
DateTime createdDate = so.CreatedDate == null? System.now(): so.CreatedDate;
if(so.SLA__c == 'Standard') {
    so.SLA_Due_Date__c = businessHours.addGmt(stdBusinessHours.Id, createdDate, 24*60*60*1000);
}
```

Edit: Note that the if-then branch is simpler-- we know that stdBusinessHours is not null, so we can avoid wasting CPU time here.

Comment: This works and I found my problem, __C was capitol not __c.  But this makes the class in itself better so I added it in.

Comment: @Dan Apex Code isn't case sensitive. You must have had a typo elsewhere.

Comment: Hrm, well it now is showing 100% coverage.  Maybe it was just due to forcing a value into it with your code so even on before updates it can test it.